# java.util.AbstractMap.equals() : what is it for try/catch?

Tags: java, exception

While writing my own custom MultiHashMap, multiTreeMap etc. classes (yes, I know these are available in Guava Library, but I needed to provide some different functionalities, so I completely rewrote these from scratch) I came across the need to write an equals() method that could compare any MultiMap, returning true if and only if the entrySet's of two MultiMaps are equivalent (same key-value mappings, regardless of the order).

As I hold the multi-values in an ordinary Map I compared my own method with API method java.util.AbstractMap.equals(), and they turned out to be pretty similar, except that I didn't use any try/catch (Java 7):

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;

    if (!(o instanceof Map))
        return false;
    Map<K,V> m = (Map<K,V>) o;
    if (m.size() != size())
        return false;

    try {
        Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The caught exceptions are RuntimeException's and beside that I can't really figure out under which circumstances they may occur.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

They use catching exceptions to make the `equals()` code shorter. I don't think it's a good practice but it works. They replace many `if`-checks by catching the exceptions.

Have a look at an example of auto-generated `equals()` method by Eclipse:

```
public class Person {
    final private String firstName;
    final private String lastName;
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

That's a correct way of implementing `equals()` to fully [fulfill its contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).
Now notice that in all the cases when some test for a proper type or for a null fails, the `equals()` method returs `false`. So the idea in the code you provided is to ommit all the checks and just catch the exception. Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    try {
        // Ommit any type-checks before type-casting
        // and replace them with catching ClassCastException:
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        // Ommit any null-checks before using the references
        // and replace them with catching NullPointerException:
        if (firstName.equals(other.firstName)
                && lastName.equals(other.lastName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (ClassCastException | NullPointerException unused) {
        // swallow the exception as it is not an error here
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you may see, the code does the same but is significantly shorter. However, it is usually considered as bad practice. Still I must admit that the code is better readable :)

The reason why it is considered as bad practice is very well described in Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf), Item 57: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions:

> Exceptions are, as their name implies, to be used only for exceptional
>   conditions; they should never be used for ordinary control flow.

Comment: Addition: One reason why it is considered bad practice is, that you have to know that it is a shorter form... Otherwise it leads to questions, as evidenced by this one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, the catch is meant to catch erroneous implementations of the `equals` method in the `V` type. The call `value.equals(m.get(key))` may throw `ClassCastException` and or `NullPointException`, when `equals` is implemented naively in `V`.

A bad implementation of `equals` in an actual `V`-Parameter type, that would be catched nicely:

```
class Whatever {
  private int attr;
  /* ... */
  @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Whatever w= (Whatever)o; // possible ClassCastException
    return (this.attr == w.attr); // possible NullPointerException
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be pretty simple: because `Map.containsKey`  method may throw both of these exceptions.

From documentation of Map interface:

```
/**
 * ....
 * @throws ClassCastException if the key is of an inappropriate type for
 *         this map (optional)
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified key is null and this map
 *         does not permit null keys (optional)
 */
boolean containsKey(Object key);
```

Although containsKey implementation in `AbstractMap` doesn't actually throw these exceptions, some custom implementations may eventually do this. And the most reliable way to handle these exceptions is to wrap `containsKey` in try-catch block.